# Protractor custom bindings don't work after multiple redirects

Tags: protractor, angular

This test does a login on a non-angular site, then switches to angular app and performs the testing. I found that regular bindings `by.css` work, but custom ones like `by.binding` don't.

```js
describe('show-rights: TC15269-restrictions', function () {

    var page = new Page();

    it('should display the restrictions', function () {
        //login on a non-angular site
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('channel/moonlight-1202275');
        //redirects to the user login
        element(by.css('#username')).sendKeys = 'User1';
        ...
        //this click will do 2 redirects, the last one being the angular app 
        signIn.click();
        browser.wait(function () {
            return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (currentUrl) {
                return currentUrl.indexOf('channel/moonlight-1202275') > -1;
            });
           }, 15000));
        //mark app as Angular
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        //this will fail
        expect(element(by.binding('formattedType')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

    });
});
```

the html

```html
<div>
    <p>{{ formattedType }}</p>
</div>
```

(Protractor version **2.5.1**, angular **1.3.17**)

To fix it, I'm refreshing the page:

```js
//mark app as Angular
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

//this fixes the custom selectors issue:
browser.refresh();
//this now works
expect(element(by.binding('formattedType')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Is there another solution?